# Getting data from two different tables into one single table?

Tags: sql, join

I have the following two tables:

```
uid   | ABC   | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
1     | val 1 | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
2     | val 2 | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
3     | val 3 | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
```

and...

```
uid   | DEF   | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
4     | val 4 | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
5     | val 5 | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
6     | val 6 | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
```

I want to end up with...

```
uid   | text  | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
1     | val 1 | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
2     | val 2 | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
3     | val 3 | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
4     | val 4 | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
5     | val 5 | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
6     | val 6 | ... (bunch of other stuff) ...
```

This looks so simple, but I just can't seem to figure out how to do this. It's not a join? Is it?

Comment: RD: Do you intend to use this data to create an actual table for later use, or do you want to collect the data as a single result?

Comment: Single result. Union was what I was looking for! Thanx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `UNION` clause will help you here.  It combines two or more result sets into one.

Try:

```
SELECT uid, ABC, OtherStuff
FROM Table1

UNION

SELECT uid, DEF, OtherStuff
FROM Table2

UNION

SELECT uid, GHI, OtherStuff
FROM Table3

ORDER BY uid
```

There is a variation on this theme with the `UNION ALL` operator.  `UNION` will explicitly remove duplicate rows while `UNION ALL` retains them.

This has ramifications beyond the simple difference in rows: to remove duplicates the `UNION` operator needs to sort the final result set.  This is overhead the `UNION ALL` operator does not experience.  Moreover, the explicit sort operation *may* cause a result set collected by `UNION` to differ in sort order when compared to `UNION ALL`.  I suggest you use an explicit `ORDER BY` statement after the result set is collected to ensure your sort order is as you intend it to be.

Please also be aware that the number of columns must match in the result sets being `UNION`ed.  It's not clear from the OP how the two tables differ in terms of the number of columns they store, and so I am hesitant to do a `UNION` between two `SELECT *` statements.

Comment: If you want to create a real table from this, the exact statement depends on the database you're using.  On most, it's "create table foo as select uid, ABC..."

Comment: @KingPong: I took the OP to mean that he/she wanted a single result set, not necessarily a real table.  I've posted a comment to the OP because you could be right.

Answer (score 1):

select * into table3 from 
    (select * from table1 union select * from table2) as tmp

Comment: Let's hope bunch of other stuff's have the same schema.

Answer (score 1):

This will union both result sets. In order to do a union the columns must be of compatible types.

```
(SELECT * FROM table1) UNION (SELECT * FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the union command will remove duplicate rows.
If that is not desired behavior, you want to use union all instead.